# force refresh object parent after add a child object jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use JpaRepository, after I create an object child in database.
I retrieve an object Parent but the new child don't exist in the parent object.
The cascade don't refresh.

For retrieve the parent object I use the method findOne or getOne but the problem is the same. I am try to use but the problem is tha same :

```html
 @Query("select u from User u where u.id=:x")
 public User findUserById(@Param("x") String id);
```

An User Have a collection of Profil and a profil have one User. In the one time, I create a Profil after I try to retrieve the user but the new profil add it don't here

```html
In User Entity 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) 
private Collection<Profil> profils; 

In profil entity 
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
private User user;
```

How I can force to refresh jpa with the new element in DB ?
Thanks

Comment: can you include your service?

Comment: why not attach all this?

Comment: Attach, I don't inderstand ?

Comment: share your entites and services please

Comment: I share the code you need, i have many fonctions. It's problem cache in jpa maybe but i don't succeed to resolv it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityManager interface has method

```
void refresh(Object entity)
```

Or you can try to access cache and evict() the entity

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(...) or evictAll();
```